# Finding intersection between two functions using Matlab or Scilab

Tags: matlab, function, intersection, scilab

I'm doing this:

```
>> plot(x,y1,x,y2);
>> x=0:0.001:5;
>> y1=sin(x)+cos(1+x.^2)-1;
>> y2 = ((1/2).*x)-1;
>> find (y1==y2)
```

And getting this:

```
ans =

   Empty matrix: 1-by-0
```

As an answer and it is simply driving me crazy! I do not know why Matlab and Scilab does not give me the answer of the intersects. I have been trying to make the intervals smaller like `x = 0:0.0001:5`; but it did not change anything. How can I make it return to me the intersection values?

Thank you.

Comment: Oh, forgot to add that these two functions have three intersection points in the selected interval.

Comment: I added an answer to show how a numerical problem like this should be handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remember that Matlab is used to find numerical solutions to problems. You are providing a discrete set of input points `x=0:0.001:5;` and asking it to calculate the discrete output points `y1[x]` and `y2[x]`. This means that `y1` and `y2` are not continuous and don't necessarily intersect as their continuous counterparts do. I don't have Matlab so I did not run your code, but your discrete functions most likely do not interset. That is to say, there is no pair of points `a = y1[x_i]` and `b = y2[x_i]` where `a = b`. Instead what you most likely want to do is look for points where `y2-y1` is on one side of zero at a particular input, and on the other side of zero for the next input. This would mean that the function's continuous conterparts would have crossed somewhere in between.

The case where the functions meet but don't cross is a little more tricky but the same kind of idea.

EDIT:

This sort of thing is easiest to wrap your head around with image so I created one illustrate what I mean.

[image: Plot of y1 and y2]

Here I used many fewer points than you are trying to use, but the idea is the same. You can see that the continuous versions of y1 and y2 cross in several places, but what you're asking matlab to do is find a point in y1 that is equal to a point in y2 for identical values of x. In this image you can see that many are close, but your computer stores floating point numbers to a very high precision and so the chances of them actually being equal is very small.

When you increase the number of sample points, the image starts to look more like its' continuous counterpart.

[image: Image with increased sample points]

Answer (score 1):

The two existing answers explain why you can't find an exact intersection so easily. But what you really need is an answer to *what to do instead* to obtain precise intersections?

In your specific case, you know the analytical functions which you want to figure out the intersection of. You can use [`fzero`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html) with an (optionally anonymous) function to find the zero of the function defined by the difference of your two original functions:

```
y1fun = @(x) sin(x)+cos(1+x.^2)-1;
y2fun = @(x) ((1/2).*x)-1;
diff_fun = @(x) y1fun(x)-y2fun(x);
x0 = 1; % starting point for fzero's zero search
x_cross = fzero(diff_fun,x0);
```

Now, this will give you *one* zero of the difference function, i.e. *one* intersection of your functions. It turns out that finding *every* zero of a function is a challenging task. Generally you have to call `fzero` multiple times with various starting points `x0`. If you suspect what your functions look like, this is not hopeless at all.

So what happens if your functions are more messy? In the general case, you can use an interpolating function to play the part of `y1fun` and `y2fun` in the example above, for instance by using [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html):

```
% generate data
xdata = 0:0.001:5;
y1data = sin(xdata)+cos(1+xdata.^2)-1;
y2data = ((1/2).*xdata)-1;

y1fun = @(x) interp1(xdata,y1data,x);
y2fun = @(x) interp1(xdata,y2data,x);
x0 = 1; % starting point for fzero's zero search
x_cross = fzero(@(x)y1fun(x)-y2fun(x),x0);
```

which leads back to the original problem. Note that `interp1` by default uses linear interpolation, depending on what your function looks like and how your data are scatted you can choose other options. Also note the option for extrapolation (to be avoided).

So in both cases, you get one crossing for each call to `fzero`. By choosing the starting points carefully, you should be able to find all the zeros, as exactly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the two vectors do not have exactly equal values anywhere. You could try to search for a smallest difference:

```
abs(y1-y2)<tolerance
```

where tolerance=0.001 is a small number